# error: index.js: [BABEL]: Cannot find module 'node:fs' in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to run react native app on Andriod but I am getting this error   `presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],`, Could someone please help me to how to resolve this issue.

```
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check **metro-react-native-babel-preset** dependency was
   installed in your package.json file.

   If not, install it using this command: `npm i metro-react-native-babel-  preset --save-dev`
2. Please check **babel.config.js** file

   There should be this code:

> ```
> module.exports = {
>
>  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
>
>  ....
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Just update node to the latest version

```bash
using sudo n latest
```

Comment: And how did you came to the conclusion it's not the latest version? And why does your suggestion solve this problem?